# How to make Input->value->type->search dynamic?

Tags: javascript, validation, sapui5

Usually a regular person's name does not contain numbers, so I added this `search` property to prevent numbers with RegEx to my `Input` element:

```
type: new sap.ui.model.type.String({}, { search: "^[^0-9]+$" })
```

But numbers should be allowed for a company's name. So how can I make this `search` value dynamic?
To visualize it:

1. "dwd3" should be invalid when it's anything other than "Company"
   [image: Not Company]
2. "dwd3" should be valid when it's a "Company"
   [image: Company]

Here's my minimal example - what I've tried so far is commented out, since it didn't work (resulted in numbers being valid at all times).

```js
// Set data model
let data = {
  "salutation": "Company",
  "name": ""
};
let oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(data);

// Create page
let oPage = new sap.m.VBox();
oPage.setModel(oModel);

// Add salutation input
oPage.addItem(
  new sap.m.Input({
    value: {
      path: "/salutation"
    }
  })
);

// Add name input
oPage.addItem(
  new sap.m.Input({
    value: {
      type: new sap.ui.model.type.String({}, {
        minLength: 2,
        maxLength: 40,
        search: "^[^0-9]+$"
        /* not working...
        search: {
          parts: [
            "/salutation",
          ],
          formatter: (salutation) =>
            salutation === "Company" ? "^.*$" : "^[^0-9]+$"
        }
        */
      }),
      path: "/name",
    },
    required: true,
  })
);

// Attach validation handlers
sap.ui.getCore().attachValidationError(function(oEvent) {
  oEvent.getParameter("element").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
});
sap.ui.getCore().attachValidationSuccess(function(oEvent) {
  oEvent.getParameter("element").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
});

// Insert page
oPage.placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the validation rule of one field depends on the value of another field, you could use events like `change` (with or without `valueLiveUpdate=true`) for validation.

A type should be something that does not depend on external life.

Another thing you could do is reacting on `change` event of your salutation field and exchange the type of the input field for the name (depending on the value of salutation)

PS: (edit) to be hontest, I wouldn't restrict a name field to anything that it may or may not contain. Depending on the country specific laws you may be allowed to use digits...

Comment: I like the solution idea with the type exchange, but I noticed that [setType](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input%23methods/setType) only sets the "outer" type property directly below the `Input` object, not below the `value` property. Do you know how to set it?